# Meteor: Reactive Image URL

Tags: javascript, image, meteor

So I have an `<img src="{{imageUrl}}">` which the url changes when selecting in a list. My problem is that when changing the url and the image is too big that its taking a while to load the previous image stays until the new image has not fully loaded. How do I fix this cause I don't want my users to feel like its still the same image but not? It should display a white background atleast. Thanks!

Comment: This is still too broad of a question. There are multiple ways of doing this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. heh what can you suggest? @ChristianFritz

Comment: how about adding loading spinner?

Comment: @user1623481 how do I apply this in meteor?

Comment: Ok I've used a package in meteor called 'imagesloaded' so that I'll show a spinner and if loaded hide it. Thanks! :)

Comment: you are welcome, glad to able to point right direction

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{{#with imageUrl}}
  <img src="{{this}}">
{{/with}}
```